# Ошибка при создании Scrolling activity

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, gradle

Я начинающий в android-разработке, при создании Scrolling activity встретился с вот такими проблемами (Gradle project sync failed.Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly). Подскажите в чем ошибка, привожу содержимое build.gradle
1 файл

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}  
}  

dependencies {  
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'  
}
```

2 файл

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.  
buildscript {  

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}  
}  

allprojects {  
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}  

task clean(type: Delete) {  
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Не надо ошибку картинкой. Надо хотя бы не только картинкой, но и текстом, чтобы поисковикам было чо индексировать. По вопросу - покажите содержимое всех `build.gradle` файлов проекта

Comment: @IvanOdintsov, Нужны не скриншоты, а текст.

Comment: @post_zeew исправил

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил

Comment: @IvanOdintsov, попробуйте всё связанное с тестами потереть `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'  `

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Возможно глупый вопрос, но что значит потереть?)

Comment: @IvanOdintsov, стереть, удалить. Вам наверняка не нужны библиотеки для тестирования.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб переустановил Android Studio и ошибок не стало, вышла более новая версия, может быть в этом была проблема.
В любом случае спасибо)